# Where can I ask how to find how an advertising agency collects data?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about how an (online) advertising agency can collect data, specifically how they collect information about how much a company may spend in a certain sector. I can't find/think of any particular SE site where this question could be posted on-topic-ally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your specific question is rather broad so I have doubts if it would be successful on any site. So before you attempt to post it I suggest you research the topic a bit more yourself to make the question more specific.

But given you scoped *advertising agency* to *online* I think a potential site might be [ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

From their [help centre](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for
>   professional and enthusiast webmasters focused on how to operate
>   websites. Questions here are commonly about
>
> - ...
> - internet marketing

It is worth noting that on the Pro Webmasters site they strongly favor questions about sites you control, in other words, you are affiliated/working for/own the website. Make sure you frame your question as such.

And I suspect their [marketing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/marketing/info) tag might cover that question, if I really take a broad scope of what is stated there:

> Questions relating to Webmasters using various Marketing methods to promote their online website(s).

form which you could argue that collecting data is part of promotion.

Alternatively [conversions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversions) is a term I believe the marketeers use, so that might be a helpful source for your research, if not an appropriate tag if you decide the question could fit on that site.

Make sure to familiarize yourself with a site and the questions and answers that get asked there before you post. When unsure, ask on their [meta](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/) site or ask in their (very active ;)) [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll try ProWebmasters.